# Is it possible to pass in arguments to an annotation within an annotation?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, annotations

I've got an annotation called **@AccessIsolation** designed to make API access isolated to only that user using Spring Security

```
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@PreAuthorize(value = "authentication.name.equals(#userId)")
public @interface AccessIsolation {
}
```

and I got a controller that looks like this

```
@DeleteMapping
public Boolean signOutCampaign(@RequestParam String userId,@RequestBody String id) {
return iCampaignAttendeeService.removeById(id);
}
```

now I want to change it a little bit since other controllers may have a different @RequestParam 'parameter name' to pass in
I can only think of a way maybe changes the annotation like this:

```
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@PreAuthorize(value = "authentication.name.equals(#userEntity)")
public @interface AccessIsolation {
    String userEntity() default "userId";
}
```

But is there a way to pass in arguments to an annotation within an annotation? because when I try to use this method but it doesn't work
how am I supposed to achieve this
Thanks in advance!